# Fill area between two lines drawn with plot()

Tags: r, plot, graph, fill

how can I fill the whole area between the two lines that were drawn with plot()

```
plot(years,investments1)
plot(years,investments2)
```

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about ggplot geom_ribbon?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1,100),
  ymin = rnorm(100,10,3),
  ymax = rnorm(100,22,2) 
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(x,ymin),color="red")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),fill="lightblue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=ymax),color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice @Eric thank you, it worked. The only problem is that when I use your code on my data the lines are dashed. Do you know how to change that to solid lines?

Comment: @Joe94, can you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?  It would make it much easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1,100),
  ymin = rnorm(100,10,3),
  ymax = rnorm(100,22,2) 
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(x,ymin),color="red")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),fill="lightblue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=ymax),color="black")

when I reproduce your example the minimum line is dotted :)

Comment: I am not sure why you get dotted lines, solid should be the default. try to add `linetype='solid'` to the geom_line term and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Thanks for your help.